# Do I need to learn Java to create an android app using phoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I am a web developer (PHP,javascript,html5) never created an android app with Java or any other language. My question is, do I need to learn Java to create apps for android and what should I know to create an awesome android app using phoneGap.

Answer (score 2):

No unless you need at some step to code a native plugin.

But it would be useful for you to understand how phonegap works behind.

Answer (score 1):

No. All you need to know are the basics of the language like including namespaces/imports, setting up some configuration files and some general familiarity with using IDEs.

You also won't need Java unless you are implementing some native functionality that is not provided by the PhoneGap API. For most simple apps a working knowledge of JavaScript, HTML and CSS will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

you most probably won't need much of Java knowledge (if any), since PhoneGap applications are basically websites with (an optional) extra bit of JavaScript controlling the device

the only thing you might need Java for is when you upgrade your Cordova versions and you have some old plugins which need to update due to code deprecation